# A Set of Sets with duplicate names?

Tags: java, collections, set

I am in the process planning my next homework assignment, which is an anagram finder. I'm using java and would like to know if you can have a Set of Set's, where each Set have the same name currentSet (the names of each set are not unique or dynamically created? If this is too vague I can post my code to put it in context. Regards.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, do you just want to define a set that holds other set objects? `HashSet<HashSet<String>> nestedSet;`?

Comment: Don't forget to add the [tag:homework] tag to homework questions.  Very useful, lots of followers.

Comment: Yes a Set that holds other set objects. How do I edit my tags to include homework?

Comment: By "name", if you are referring to variable name, then please remember, they are just references to actual objects on heap. And same reference can point one object one time and another object (of same time) at another time.

Comment: Sorry yes I did mean variable name. I should of been clearer in my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hunter already mentioned, you can have Set of Sets. The code would be something like following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestingSets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Set<String>> mainSet = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
        Set<String> s;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            s = new HashSet<String>();
            s.add("Hi "+i);
            mainSet.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```